# SMALL()-Function in PowerPivot

Tags: powerpivot, measure

I am trying to create a measure in powerpivot which should give me the ten lowest prices per article – and then put that measure in a pivottable to see the customer's name behind that price.

But I realized there is no such thing in powerpivot then SMALL() as Excel does. Am Did I miss this function in powerpivot or do I need to solve it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The `RANKX` function is what you are probably looking for: [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492185.aspx)

This allows you to create a ranking for a table based upon an expression. By specifying the order Parameter as 1 you would get a smallest-to-highest ranking which would be aquivalent to `SMALL()`

Alternatively you could use `RANK.EQ` to create a calculated column on your table which would contain the ranking. You could then use the Top 10 filter in a Pivot table to get your desired result: [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492169.aspx)