# How to create a column showing if a value is in the bottom 10 values?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a large data set that contains details about objects that are currently on an extension. The extensions are given a specific due date. Some of the extensions are past their due date.

I'm struggling to work out how to create a column in PowerPivot for O365 Excel that will return a yes/no value depending on if the object is one of the 5 most overdue extensions. So far nothing I've tried has worked at all.

Example with fake data:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------------+------------+
|    ID     | Urgency | Bus Days Remaining |  Due Date  |
+-----------+---------+--------------------+------------+
| 118017544 | Overdue |               -487 | 1/04/2017  |
|  34960939 | Overdue |                -97 | 30/09/2018 |
|  10695082 | Overdue |               -364 | 20/09/2017 |
| 166236826 | Overdue |                -86 | 15/10/2018 |
| 166236826 | Overdue |                -86 | 15/10/2018 |
|  34944450 | Overdue |               -437 | 9/06/2017  |
|  69427293 | Overdue |               -446 | 29/05/2017 |
|  56280961 | Overdue |               -437 | 9/06/2017  |
|  12535364 | Overdue |               -176 | 11/06/2018 |
|  46296100 | Overdue |               -163 | 28/06/2018 |
| 171666963 | Overdue |               -122 | 24/08/2018 |
+-----------+---------+--------------------+------------+
```

The calculated column should be able to put a "Yes" next to 5 rows in this data that are the oldest.

Factors that might be important:

Multiple extensions can share a due date but be separate extensions. This makes me think that the formula needs to be based off of the "Bus Days Remaining" column value

Excel has a function in Pivot Tables where you only show the Top 10 values. This isn't an option for me because using that filter means you cannot drill into the Pivot Tables data.

Any help you could provide would be great :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which is the "most overdue extension" in your example and why?

Comment: The most overdue extension is whatever row has the lowest value in "Bus Days Remaining". The "Bus Days Remaining" column is a count of days between now and the "Due Date". So any extensions that are overdue will have a negative value.

Basically I need the formula to work out what are the 10 'most overdue' extensions based on the Bus Days Remaining column and for each column in the data, say "Yes this is one of the most overdue extensions" or "No this isn't one of the 10 most overdue extensions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula.

```
=C2<=SMALL(C$2:C$12,5)
```

If the 5th and 6th smallest are equal the formula will return TRUE for more than 5 items.

Comment: The "SMALL" formula doesn't appear to work in PowerPivot. Sadly the formula is required to be in PowerPivot for what I am working on.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about PowerPivot but, as a shot in the dark, might the AGGREGATE version of the above have better luck? `=C2<=AGGREGATE(15,6,C$2:C$12,5)`

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284253/small-function-in-powerpivot

Comment: Your link led me to the answer :)

Ended up using the DAX formula:

```
=RANKX(DISTINCT('TABLE_NAME'[Bus Days Remaining]),'TABLE_NAME'[Bus Days Remaining],'TABLE_NAME'[Bus Days Remaining],ASC)
```

This gives me a calculated column that lists the rows 'Overdue Rank' as I'm calling it. 

From here I can use another calculated column to give the Yes/No value depending on the overdue rank.

Thanks heaps :)